# Как сделать Distinct по двум полям Hibernate (не используя Criteria) через запрос?

Tags: java, hibernate

В таблице находятся два поля с именами. Родитель и сын. Нужно найти все уникальные комбинации.

Answer (score 2):

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select distinct se.name, se.parentName from SomeEntity se");
List<Object[]> uniqueNames = query.list();
```